# Example of using EventFilter in java to test log messages

Tags: java, akka, akka-testkit

I can't find a working Java example of how to use the EventFilter functionality made available in the Akka TestKit. I want to assert that something was logged and while searching I arrived at this link in the documentation:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/testing.html#Expecting_Log_Messages

As far as I can see, the example code is outdated or not compiling.

Examples in Scala are not a problem. I also understand how the EventListener should be used. I just can't figure out how to use it in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much all the sample code in the docs is both compiled and run as a part of the Akka build.

While writing this answer I noticed the actual test not inheriting the right test suite and therefore not running (noted and fixed in [ticket 22439](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/22439)) the sample test case for `EventFilter` does however work without modification.

You can see the complete test that contains the sample here:
https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/e46a1f6b504eddea340fe274c94a6c1692d9ae5a/akka-docs/rst/java/code/docs/testkit/TestKitDocTest.java#L420

Comment: Apparently, there are two EventFilters, one top level class and one as an innerclass of TestKit. I was trying to get the top level class to work (akka.testkit.EventFilter) What is the difference between these two?

Comment: JavaTestKit.EventFilter is the Java API, while akka.testkit.EventFilter is the Scala API. We are looking at improving the separation of the Java and Scala APIs in the testkit to make this a bit less confusing in this ticket: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/21858